# Printing value of variable with echo -e option

Tags: shell, echo

Echo when used with -e option doesn't seem to output/expand value of a variable

Using this way as it's been part of framing json file

Tried with backtick to expand variable value. And also with (( to eval as expression

```
echo -e '"compVersion:","$compLatestVer",' >> framed.json
```

eg : with compLatestVer=2.3.4
When I echo it, it just prints

```
echo -e '"compVersion:","$compLatestVer",'
```

to file rather than expanded value

I tried with

```
echo -e '"compVersion:","`$compLatestVer`",'
```

Also with

```
echo -e '"compVersion:","((compLatestVer))",'
```

without luch

```
echo -e '"compVersion:","2.3.4",'
```

Comment: Nothing inside single quote`'` is expanded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `echo`. Use `printf` instead.

```
printf '"compVersion": "%s"' "$compLatestVer"
```

However, building up a JSON value piecemeal like this is also wrong; use a tool like `jq` to generate it for you.

(I adjusted the format string, since it looks like you are trying to output key/value pairs for a JSON object.)

Comment: Many thanks - this helped. Below is final version which addressed problem from OP
`printf '"compVersion": "%s,\n"' "$compLatestVer"`